# Angular $http then resolve for multiple calls in _.each

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am trying to fetch multiple data from $http inside _.each and show the combined data in $scope.tasksData.

But the problem is _.each is executed later and returned null first,
Please guide how to resolve this.

Thanks

```
var tasksList, processingStageId;

var apiURL = "http://localhost:9080/caseDetails/" + $stateParams.caseId + "?_=1461046349867";



var stagesList = $http.get(apiURL).then(function(resdata, status, headers, config) {

return resdata;

}).then(function(stagesData) {

stageId = stagesData.data.childStages;
var allTasksData = [];
var self = this;

_.each(stageId, function(item) {
    var stagesApiURL = "http://localhost:9080/stageDetails/" + item.stage.stageId;

    $http.get(stagesApiURL).then(function(taskData, status, headers, config) {
        //_.extend(allTasksData, taskData.data);            
        allTasksData.push(taskData.data);

    });
});

return allTasksData;

}).then(function(allTasksData) {
console.log("Hello");

_.each(allTasksData, function(data) {
    $scope.tasksData.concat(data);
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For get data after resolve all request, use $q.all([prom, prom, prom])

```
.then(function(stagesData){
    var stageId = stagesData.data.childStages;
    var tasks = [];

    _.each(stageId, function(item){
        var stagesApiURL = "http://localhost:9080/stageDetails/" + item.stage.stageId;
        var req = $http.get(stagesApiURL).then(function(taskData, status, headers, config){            
            return taskData.data;
        });
        tasks.push(req);
    });

    //Merge all promise request. Resolve when all request resolved
    return $q.all(tasks);

})
/**
 * allTasksData - [taskData.data, taskData.data , ...]
 */
.then(function(allTasksData){
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject a `$q` service and use `$q.all` function

```
var stagesList = $http.get(apiURL).then(function(resdata, status, headers, config) {
  return resdata;
})
.then(function(stagesData) {
  stageId = stagesData.data.childStages;

  var self = this;

  return $q.all(
    _.map(stageId, function(item) {
      var stagesApiURL = "http://localhost:9080/stageDetails/" + item.stage.stageId;

      return $http.get(stagesApiURL).then(function(taskData, status, headers, config) {
          return taskData.data;
      });
    })
  );
})
.then(function(allTasksData) {
  console.log("Hello");

  _.each(allTasksData, function(data) {
      $scope.tasksData.concat(data);
  });
});
```

Small explanation: we use `map` instead of `each` to generate an array of promises. Then we pass an array of promises to the `$q.all` function which returns a new promise with an array of `taskData.data` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is there to help you.

According to documentation, it:

> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.

You register all your calls and then when all of them are resolved, you do what you need with your data.

Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsengel/mc3p01nb/) (not mine) with how it works.